# Reading local .xml using angular5 HttpClient

Tags: angular

I am trying to read local .xml file using angular5 HttpClient. My service is like this ::

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private _http:HttpClient) { }

  getFile() {
    const _headers = new HttpHeaders();
    const headers = _headers.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
    return this._http.get('../assets/data.xml',{headers: _headers});
  }

}
```

But I am getting error

message
:
"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:4200/assets/data.xml"
name
:
"HttpErrorResponse"
ok
:
false
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
return this._http.get('../assets/data.xml',{headers: _headers,responseType: 'text'});
```